# Getting Error "Buffer reader can not be resolver to a type" in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

i have also imported files need for it but even then it is giving error this is is quit correct i have also imported files for it but i am new to jsp so i am not getting the error  ..
my code is

```
<%-- 
    Document   : host
    Created on : Nov 25, 2011, 3:15:31 AM
    Author     : Administrator
--%>
<%@page import="Pages.Host"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Network Monitoring</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />


    </head>
    <body style="background: whitesmoke" >
        <%@page language="java" import="java.io.*" %>
        <%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
        <% try
                               {
            String strpath="/var/random.txt";
            String line;
            BufferReader objReader=new BufferReader(new FileReader(strpath));
            line=objReader.readLine();
            while(line !=null)
                               {
                int num_from_file=0;
                int my_random_num=0;
                out.println(line);

                num_from_file=(int)Interger.parseInt(line);
                Random_generator=new Random(num_from_file);
                my_random_num=generator.netInt();

                line=objReader.readLine();

                               }
                       }
        catch(IOException e){}
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopes for your suggestions .. .

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You need to import it

add

```
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
```

and then correct the spelling :)

Comment: There's already an import for `java.io.*` - it's only the name that was causing the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I missed to read import in the middle of the code :)

Comment: I hope you didn't change `<%@page import="java.io.*"%>`

Comment: just import `<%@page import="java.io.*"%>` once in your JSP,

Comment: @ thanks for all for your suggestions i am using virtual machine and netbeans platform but my issue is regarding some keywords in my code which i miss spelled because intellicense in not working at jsp page

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you mean [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) rather than `BufferReader`. When the compiler tells you it can't find a type, it's worth double-checking that it really is the type you meant :)

Answer (score 0):

you had      <%@page language="java" import="java.io.*" %>  in which there is no Class file in the name  BufferReader so Change it to BufferedReader and then the compiler will find it